# Dynamic iframe in php

Tags: php, css, iframe

I'm trying to set up a development server used by designers to test CSS before a deployment. The caveat is I want to be able to load HTML / PHP into an iframe, but have a variable passed to it that will allow me to swap the link to CSS from within the iframe. This will emulate the control I have over the production ad feeds that come via iframes. 
I attempted a function that returned HTML with a variable css link, but it will not come back as an iframe, of course. The iframe will ensure the included css is the only css that will be used, and that the main page css will not affect the content of the iframe. 
How can I load an iframe with a variable CSS link?

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: There is now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an iframe with a query string parameter on the source.

`<iframe height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="/inc/mockads.php?css=<?=($settings['stylesheet']);?>">`

which will pass the pre-defined stylesheet to the markup to be iframed. Then, in the mockads.php file, I add the logic to do:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['css']) && strlen($_GET['css']) )
{
    $stylesheet = $_GET['css'];
}
?>
```

Then the rest of the markup, with the link set like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$stylesheet;?>" type="text/css"  media="all">`